# Android version code at AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest

I am making android mobile game with unity.

When I need to upload newer version of my game to play store console, I need to change [Bundle version], [Bundle version code] at unity's build setting.

This is fine, but should I also change AndroidManifest.xml's

```
android:versionCode="12"
android:versionName="1.11"
```

too as match with unity's build setting?

Tiresome and want to pass this.

Comment: are you using android-studio and gradle to build ?

Comment: no, but I used eclipse for make some android library work for 3rd party sdk integration.

Comment: Is you `AndroidManifest` generated automatically by Unity or did you write a replacement yourself?

Answer (score -1):

No need to change versionName and versionCode in AndroidManifest.xml manually.
Unity3D will change them for you according to current PlayerSettings values when exporting.

Comment: If he wrote a replacement Unity won't write neither version code nor version name.